# C# Threads, always getting error

Tags: c#, multithreading

please help me figure out with this code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AionInterface;
using System.Threading;

    namespace mover
    {
        public class MoveToCoord : IAionInterface
        {
            Thread tr;
            Thread repeater;
            public MoveToCoord()
            {
                tr = new Thread(LetsWork);
                repeater = new Thread(Repeater);
            }

            public void Sleep(int ms)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(ms);
            }

            public void SetPosition(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                Game.Player.SetPosition(x, y, z);
            }

            public void OnClose()
            {
                return;
            }

            public void OnLoad()
            {
                //Game.Register("FindTarget", "f", KeysModifier.Control);
            }

            public void OnRun()
            {
                repeater.Start();
            }

            public void Repeater()
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    tr.Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(6000);
                }
            }

            public void LetsWork()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                SetPosition(1926, 1771, 163);
                Thread.Sleep(1400);
                SetPosition(1930, 1774, 163);
                Thread.Sleep(1400);
            }

            public void CancelScript()
            {
                Game.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to execute method LetsWork 5 times with delay 6 seconds, unfortunatelly I do not know any programming language, still hard to understand to me how Threads works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need 5 threads or you need it 5 times from the same thread with a delay of 6 s. Do a for next in LetsWork and add a delay, use only one thread.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show you've made some effort as this isn't a "write code for me" type site. If you don't know any programming languages, I suggest you learn C#.

Comment: jfoll - @ReticulatedSpline advise is sound, but don't let him discourage you.  I think the issue is your understanding of threading

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline you clearly see an attempt in the code. Users have different skills.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck up voted comment.  I'm assuming since i see the mention of Game.Close() he's trying to create a game.  I know Unity using C# in their gaming so i'm guessing he wants to do threading here.  I wish the OP had provided the error

Comment: This question is unclear to me. What are you expecting here ? You need to clearly state your question.

Comment: Sorry, but how does a user who says they don't know programming languages be expected to do anything programming-related? That makes no sense.

Comment: Just if code it without extended thread, application is freezing while execute Sleep. I'm not found in google anything else except threading :\

Comment: Threading is actually an advanced topic too. I suggest you do some reading first. If you are still learning basic progamming, then threading is not the first topic to tackle. Or you end up with code you don't understand. Don't write or use code you don't understand.

Comment: Yes i'll inform myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need your GUI thread and one worker thread to avoid freezing.
Based on your code you can do the same thing but simplified to using only 1 worker thread. As a side not you really need to post your error, because I cannot possibly execute your code, I don't know if the below code will fix the error yes or no. It just fixes a design issue.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AionInterface;
using System.Threading;

    namespace mover
    {
        public class MoveToCoord : IAionInterface
        {
            Thread tr;
            public MoveToCoord()
            {
                tr = new Thread(LetsWork);
            }

            public void Sleep(int ms)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(ms);
            }

            public void SetPosition(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                Game.Player.SetPosition(x, y, z);
            }

            public void OnClose()
            {
                return;
            }

            public void OnLoad()
            {
                //Game.Register("FindTarget", "f", KeysModifier.Control);
            }

            public void OnRun()
            {
                tr.Start();
            }

            public void LetsWork()
            {
                for (int i=0;i<6;++i){
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    SetPosition(1926, 1771, 163);
                    Thread.Sleep(1400);
                    SetPosition(1930, 1774, 163);
                    Thread.Sleep(1400);

                    Thread.Sleep(6000);
                } 
            }

            public void CancelScript()
            {
                Game.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to run LetsWork 5 times with a 6 second delay you don't need to thread it.  If your goal is to run LetsWork 5 times, 5 times simultaneously with  a 6 second delay then use threading.

The basic premise of threading is to execute code simultaneously.

Comment: Just if code it without extended thread, application is freezing while execute Sleep. I'm not found in google anything else except threading :\